# Access job specific parameter in the scheduler in Hadoop 2.0+

Tags: java, hadoop, scheduler, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to write a YARN scheduler that takes into consideration a deadline. I know that additional parameters can be specified with [-D](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#Generic_Options) or

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("test", "123");

Job job = new Job(conf);
```

Those parameters can be accessed in map/reduce methods easily through a 'context' parameter, but I'm not sure how to access them in the [scheduler](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/scheduler/fifo/FifoScheduler.java#L842) based on the ApplicationId.
Any idea on how to do that?